# Android Studio: Enum auto-completion of switch case

Tags: autocomplete, enums, android-studio, switch-statement

Is there any auto-complete shortcut or code-generation command in Android Studio that creates a stub

```
switch (myEnum){

}
```

statement containing all of the possible `case` statements for a defined `enum` as in [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618797/eclipse-java-enum-auto-completion-of-switch-case)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Put the caret on "switch", press Alt-Enter, select "Create missing 'switch' branches".

Comment: I tried that, may be I am doing wrong. Will you please explain?

Comment: Create the "switch" stub as in:
'switch(*enum_instance*){
    <- put caret here
}'
and press Alt-Enter. A small context menu should appear with an entry "Create missing 'switch' branches"

Comment: ⌥(Option) + Enter on Mac.

Comment: I have tried this in the past but this doesn't seem to be working now. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Enum.class

```
public enum
myEnum{
Item1,
Item2,
Item3,
Item4
}
```

EnumSwitchImplement.class

```
private Enum.myEnum mMyEnum;

switch(mMyEnum){
//put cursor here and press Alt + Enter

/*a box will come with option "create missing 'switch' branches"
select.*/
}
```

//your switch will convert to

```
switch(mMyEnum){
case Item1:
break;
case Item2:
break;
case Item3:
break;
case Item4:
break;
}
```

This works on Android Studio.
Haven't check on Eclipse. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just place the mouse pointer over `switch` and then wait for some time. An yellow bulb will be shown as below. Click on that yellow bulb (or press ALT+Enter) and click on the option `Create missing 'switch' branches` option.

[image]

This will auto create the switch case-break statements as below.
[image]

Hope this helps someone.